# Which C# data structure should be used to store n number (e.g. 1million) of records

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I have a `Person` class and my design needs to have a capacity of up to a million persons. I need to be able to load in memory. I've tried various ways and they work ok for small sets but when the count gets anywhere close to a million it takes too much time and memory. Are there any C# data structures or strategies that are specialized for what I'm trying to do which is store N number (e.g. 1 million) of records for below Class?

```
Class Person
{
    string Id {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: use long. that will do

Comment: Depends a lot on what you are trying to do.  All data structures are better for other things. For example a LinkedList is super fast at adding records since you always add them at the start of the list but is slow finding items because you have to loop through the whole list to find it. In your case you are using an Id so my guess is that you trying to imitate a database. In that case I would say that the best options are either a DataTable or a Dictionary(using the id as key).

Comment: You mean a structure to have a million `Person` instances? What about `List<Person>` or `Dictionary<string, Person>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say **store** a million `Person` records my assumption is that you mean *persistent* storage and that you're not going to enter them by hand every time you run your app. One way to achieve this goal would be to use one of the various SQLite versions to store the records in a database format. When these records are retrieved with a query, the data can be used to populate a simple data structure like `List<Person>` or a more complex data structure like `DataTable` or `ViewModel`. To keep things simple, this example uses the `sqlite-net-pcl` NuGet package.

Here, the `Person` class has been modified with additional tags to let SQLite know how to configure the table:

```
[Table("Persons")]
class Person
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{Id} {FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

The first snippet creates a temporary database in memory and inserts three records to demo a few basics. To store it on disk, just change `databasePath: ":memory:"` to a writable path like `{MyAppDataFolderPath}\{MyDatabaseName}.db`.)

```
var database = new SQLiteConnection(databasePath: ":memory:");
database.CreateTable<Person>();
database.Insert(new Person { Id = "Admin.1", FirstName = "Tom", LastName = "Hanks" });
database.Insert(new Person { Id = "Admin.2", FirstName = "Tom", LastName = "Holland" });
database.Insert(new Person { Id = "Staff.1", FirstName = "Tom", LastName = "Cruise" });
```

Here are a few example of retrieving instances of `Person` from the database and putting them in a `List<Person>` data structure.

```
// How many Toms?
int count = database.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Persons WHERE FirstName='Tom'");
Console.WriteLine($"Found {count} persons named 'Tom'");

// Match a pattern
Console.WriteLine("\nList Admin:");
List<Person> recordset = 
    database.Query<Person>(
        "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Id LIKE 'Admin.%'");
foreach (Person record in recordset)
    Console.WriteLine(record.ToString());

// Match multiple properties
Console.WriteLine("\nGet ID for Tom Cruise Person");
Person person = 
    database.Query<Person>(
        "SELECT ID FROM Persons WHERE FirstName='Tom' AND LastName='Cruise'"
    ).First();
Console.WriteLine($"ID is {person.Id}");
```

As commented, your question could be answered in many different ways and this is just one approach, but it's one that I use in my own production code base which is shared between PC, iOS and Android versions.

[image: console output]